# how can I convert a file with .arff format to .txt file format?

Tags: file-type, file-conversion

How can I convert from .arff file to .txt file? I couldn't find any converter in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> This format is basically just a text file[...]

Can't you just right click and open it with notepad ?

Answer (score 0):

.arff or Attribute-Relation File Format (ARFF) files are ASCII text files so changing there extension to .txt file would work.

More [Info](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can open with sublime editer